# Data loader to insert data

Tags: data-loader

Iam trying to upload data into custom object called "Migration" and i have Process on this object in process builder.i tried to insert 350 records into Migration using data loader.If i insert with 10 records,it is not giving any error.If i try to insert 350 into the object,then all the records are getting failed.Not able to figured it out what is happening.Need help,Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 3010G0000004kSH. Flow error messages: <b>An <br>An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow.  Please contact your system administrator for more information.  Contact your administrator for help.

Comment: Are you update any other record on process builder, or is there any trigger getting executed on the same time?

Comment: @Hemant,If i inactive the process..iam not getting that error

Comment: Yes.Iam updating the record.

Comment: Have you made sure, that all the required fields are getting populating when you are updating the other  record, through process builder?

Comment: if I send same records 10 by 10,all the records got inserted successfully.

Comment: One of the reason i can think of, is there is some trigger getting fired on update of the record from process builder, which causes the governor limits to exceed and gives the error

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is probably - with the limited information you gave - that your batch size on the dataloader is to big causing governor limits to be exceeded.

Comment: by default data loader size will be 200,to overcome this error shall i decrease the limit like it will be 100.can u share which governor limit it will hit.

Answer (score 0):

The process builder can be tricky like that. If you want to do the dataload without making any changes i would change the batch size as Koen Certyn says. 
You know that it will run with 10 so you can start with that, it would take longer time to do the dataload. The way you change the batch size is by clicking settings and change the Batch size. 
Best regards, 
Christian.